# Typo3 - Save GET-Value to Session

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

Im currently developing a extension for Typo3 8.7 and want to store a GET-Parameter in the session of the frontend user. 
I know I can store it with `$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->setKey('ses', 'foo')` but how could I hook into every page request?

If I use a hook I can't access `$GLOBALS['TSFE']` (Because it is not loaded?).

If someone has an idea how to hook into every page request (frontend) and access `$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user` , it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a USER_INT script or plugin through TypoScript using page.20 (or a different number if that's already in use)

Comment: `USER_INT` scripts in TYPO3 8 are always embedded in an extension.
`plugins` in TYPO3 are always content-elements, that is probably not the right way as you had to add that plugin then on every page.

Comment: Yes, `USER_INT` scripts should be embedded in an extension. The OP stated he was making an extension, so that shouldn't be a problem. Plugins are not always content elements. They can be added through TypoScript, so you don't have to manually add it for each page.

Comment: Yeah, good that you mention about the TypoScript-option, nevertheless the plugins still represent content(elements) then ;-) But it might be a matter of view, so no need to define a definition of that ;-)

Comment: The extension is loaded on every page, so it worked. Thx

Answer (score 0):

The variable name is `$GLOBALS['TSFE']`, so probably you never got access to it because you missed the `S` at the end.

Comment: It was copy-paste error. Just double checked, $GLOBALS['TSFE'] was null. I think the variable just isn't declared in the hook i tried to use.